# Remove accents on tags url

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I've made a tag cloud on Jekyll with jekyll-tagging plugin. The plugin works fine, but when I need to iterate through tags and append the name to a url, the accents are still there which causes a error, even when using the slugify method.

I'm new to Ruby and I haven't found any native Ruby methods to remove the accents.

Comment: Maybe related to this issue (with an solution) on the [jekyll-tagging github page](https://github.com/pattex/jekyll-tagging/issues/54)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
require 'open-uri'

URI.encode("sadòlmòà")
```

Comment: Sorry, but i'm really noob, where i require that on Jekyll?